# Homebrew installation error: "not a valid ref: refs/remotes/origin/master"?

Tags: macos, homebrew

I have tried to install Homebrew on macOS Monterey by following the instructions at https://brew.sh/.

But it resulted in:

```
error: Not a valid ref: refs/remotes/origin/master
Error: Fetching /opt/homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core failed!
fatal: invalid upstream 'origin/master'
Failed during: /opt/homebrew/bin/brew update --force --quiet
```

[image: 1]

Answer (score 17):

I encountered this error on my brand new Macbook Pro with the M2 processor. What worked for me was removing the contents of the homebrew directory

```
rm -rf /opt/homebrew
```

Then running the uninstall script (its the same as the intall script on the [homebrew](https://brew.sh/) except change the last part from `install` to `uninstall`. Assuming the link has not changed on the homebrew website I ran these two commands and it installed successfully.

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/uninstall.sh)"
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
```

You can run `brew -v` or `brew doctor` to check if your install is good.

Comment: This worked for me, aside from running the uninstall command. Since I had already removed the directory, the uninstall script produces an error.

Comment: > brand new Macbook Pro with the M2 processor... Same. This worked for me.

Comment: I got a new MacBook too with M2 and this helped me install brew successfully!

Comment: TYVM; All I did was `rm -rf /opt/homebrew` and then ran the install script again ... don't know why that worked, but it did ... 2021 Macbook Pro 14", M1 Pro, Monterey/12.6.1.

Answer (score 0):

My error was after a failed previous install with WSL... so same on windows, only:

```
cd /home 
sudo rm -rf homebrew/
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked on M1.

```
 /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/uninstall.sh)"
git config --global core.compression 0
git config --global http.postBuffer 1048576000
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh)"
```